# How to convert Date Difference value from float to int?

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I'm trying to calculate date difference using `JavaScript`.

**My Code:**

```
function getELECurrentdifference($this1)
  {
    var CtrDate = new Date('');
    if($this1.datepicker("getDate") != null)
    {
      var ELEcertCurrentDiff= $this1.datepicker("getDate") - CtrDate;    
      var result = ELEcertCurrentDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * +1;
      //$("#ELEcertDiff").text(result);
      document.getElementById("ELEcertCurrentDiff").value = result;
    }
  }
```

But I got a value in float.

**Output:**

> 25.39119292824074

How I can convert it to integer value like **25** only.

Any kind of help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use `Math.floor` or `Math.trunc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor). `Math.floor` will round down to the nearest integer any given number.

You could also use [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc), which will remove any fractional digits.